# unable to find the array object is continuous or not

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

**Below is the scenario i have tried**

*I tried to find the continuity or discontinuity between range of numbers.*

**Here is the criterial.**

1 - 100,
101 - 300 after this object there is discontinuity, it will be 301. I need to find it is discontinuity or not like that.
401 - 500.

**we nee do find the continue or discontinue.**

**Below is my object** :

```
const obj = [{start:1, end: 100},
    {start:401, end: 500},
    {start:101, end: 300}]
```

*I used sorting to sort the start filed from the array.*

After i used forEach and i used if condition to check current object end value is equal to next object start. ***any help Thanks***.

```js
const obj = [{start:1, end: 100},
{start:401, end: 500},
{start:101, end: 300}]

obj.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return a.start - b.start;
})

obj.forEach((arr, i)=>{
    
})
```

Comment: Please fix the [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) of your question

Comment: What is the output supposed to be for `const obj = [{start:1, end: 100},
    {start:401, end: 500},
    {start:101, end: 300}]`?

Comment: out put : true or false  ( number of objects we need to sort, after we need to find continue or not - each object)

Comment: there is a discontinuity after 300, next object it will be 301 but it is  {start:401, end: 500} in given array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like that:

```js
 let obj = [{start:1, end: 100},
    {start:401, end: 500},
    {start:101, end: 300}]

    obj.sort(function(a, b) { 
        return a.start - b.start;
    })
    for (let i = 0; i < obj[obj.length - 1].end; i ++) {
      if (i + 1 < obj.length && obj[i].end + 1 !== obj[i + 1].start) {
        console.log('Discontinuity: ', obj[i].end + 1);
      }
    }
    //With forEach if needed
    obj.forEach( (element, i) => {
      if (i + 1 < obj.length && obj[i].end + 1 !== obj[i + 1].start) {
         console.log('Discontinuity: ', obj[i].end + 1);
      }
    })
```

Comment: Its valid output, but instead of for is it possible to use **forEach. Because number of iterations are very high, its around 700 times its looping. Performance is very less.

Comment: The complexity of the for is O(n), which is one of the best case scenario, just lose for O(1). Maybe the problem is on the `sort` function, which I'm not sure it's complexity. So for the problem that you describe, this is the answer.

Comment: Now, I got it, I will edit and add with forEach solution